# How to track a program/process is running in Ubuntu?

Tags: java, docker, ubuntu

I need to find a way to track that a program P is running. My program is in an Ubuntu docker container, it is a java one. I need another program to periodically tell me that my program P is running. If it fails to send me that message I will have to re-start the program. Is there a way to find out this? We are afraid that the program or the docker container could stop running and affect the user experience.

Comment: Why write that yourself? There are a ton of tools out there that do that job already. Check out https://superuser.com/questions/65318/automatically-restart-a-unix-job-if-it-goes-down for a starting point

Comment: Beyond that, your question is too broad and unspecific. Would you expect us to write (java) code for you? Or a shell script? So, yes: A) use existing technology and B) see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question

Comment: Believe it or not, this is some new kind of task for me. I was also considering a cron job to verify if the respective docker container is still running, and another cron job inside the docker container to tell me if the app (by process id) still exist in the memory of that docker container. However, to send a message to my email about that information -from one of those cron jobs- in case there is a problem as that might need the installation of mail server and the memory for a docker container could be a limit. Again, I am still brainstorming. Thx

Answer (score 1):

Though, the question is to broad to be answered clearly I'll try to offer some solutions.

First of all, if your `java` process 'fails' the container will end it's work. Based on this you can identify if your app is running simply by performing `docker ps`.

If you want some handwritten solution you can implement a health-check rest endpoint in you application and hit it periodically to ensure the app is running.

Answer (score 1):

you could setup a restart policy on the docker container, that way if java encounters an exception and exits, it will automatically try to restart the container.

In the `docker run` command, just add `--restart unless-stopped`, this way it will always try to restart unless a stop command was send by docker itself.

more information on this functionality can be found at:
https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/start-containers-automatically/#restart-policy-details